# VBA to change export to PDF Range

Tags: vba

Hi I currently have a script to export to PDF a certain Range so that two pages are exported in one document. Currently I am exporting A1:W44 as one page and want to export A44:W44 as a second page on the same document.

Ideally, I want to add an IF function to Print_Range() to change the print out 2 pages (from A1:W44 being page 1 and A45:W88 being page 2) when the value of W44 = 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub set_variables()

reportsht = "report"
strow = 2
slopessht = "slopes"
Set reportrng = Range("A1:W44")
xpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

End Sub

Sub print_range()

Call set_variables

stval = Sheets(reportsht).Range("z7")
endval = Sheets(reportsht).Range("z8")

For i = stval + strow - 1 To endval + strow - 1

    siteid = Sheets(slopessht).Cells(i, 2)

    If siteid = "" Then Exit For

    'create sheet
    Call createsht(siteid)

Next i

End Sub

Sub createsht(siteid)

    pdffilename = xpath & "\" & siteid & ".pdf"
    Sheets(reportsht).Range("z5") = siteid
    Calculate

    reportrng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=pdffilename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
    From:=1, to:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: I just realized I had 'From:=1, to:=1' on the code, which was locking the number of pages I could export. So that issue is fixed. Now I just need to add a function to increase the reportrng when cell W44=2